# Is this possible to setInterval with custom ID so I can clear it later on from another services?

Tags: javascript

I want to register a new interval using `setInterval` method that will be running until I stop it. I want to stop it from another service (api route).
But the problem is that I don't have the ID of the interval. All I have is this when log the interval object:

```
let interval = setInterval(() => console.log(`Hello World`), 3000);
console.log(`interval:`, interval);

// we got this in the log:

interval: Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 3000,
  _idlePrev: [TimersList],
  _idleNext: [TimersList],
  _idleStart: 2765,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: 3000,
  _destroyed: false,
  [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 29,
  [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1 }
```

Comment: No that is not what Ive asked

Answer (score 1):

That **is** the "id" of the interval, in Node.js. (It would be a number on browsers, but on Node.js it's a `Timeout` object.) It's what you pass to [`clearInterval`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_clearinterval_timeout). So pass that object to the other service that you want to stop the interval from.

---

In a comment you've said:

> But I cannot send it to another service directly, the service should pull it from DB or something. And I tried to store it in MongoDB and got an error because mongo wont store such an object.

Assuming the other service is in the same process (otherwise, it can't cancel the timer), you could write a module to assign timers numeric IDs:

```
let lastId = 0;
const timers = new Map();

export function mySetInterval(callback, ms) {
    const id = ++lastId;
    timers.set(id, setInterval(callback, ms));
    return id;
}

export function myClearInterval(id) {
    const timer = timers.get(id);
    if (timer) {
        timers.delete(id);
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

Setting an interval timer:

```
import { mySetInterval } from "./my-module";

saveTimerIdInDB(mySetInterval(() => console.log(`Hello World`), 3000));
```

Clearing it:

```
import { myClearInterval } from "./my-module";

myClearInterval(getTimerIdFromDB());
```

**Note:** I'm using JavaScript standard module syntax there ("ESM"). But you can do the same thing with Node.js's older module syntax ("CJS"), switch to `exports.mySetInterval = ...` and `const mySetInterval = require(...)` accordingly.

Comment: But I cannot send it to another service directly, the service should pull it from DB or something. And I tried to store it in MongoDB and got an error because mongo wont store such an object.

Comment: @Raz - *"But I cannot send it to another service directly, the service should pull it from DB or something."* Why? And is this service in the same process as the code scheduling the interval?

Comment: Anyway, if it isn't, you can't clear the timer. If it is, see my update.

Comment: Maybe I can do this using a cronjob instead?